# Fat-tailed data and SVM

Tags: svm, outliers, fat-tails

Does SVM perform poorly when fat-tailed data with outliers is used?  What are some things that could be done to improve learning with such data?  Does the choice of kernel and/or kernel parameter change?

For dealing with outliers, I was thinking of transforming the data such that values +/- 2 standard deviations are assumed to be outliers and would be replaced with the closest marginal values. (then transform the data into the range [-0.9, 0.9])

Assuming fat-tails are undesireable with SVM, what are some transformations that could be considered to help alleviate the fat-tails?

(I'm using LIBSVM with the Matlab interface)

Comment: See http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/25934/support-vector-regression-on-skewed-high-kurtosis-data/28969#28969